# Exported environmental variable via docker entrypoint are not shown when logging into the container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-swarm, docker-entrypoint

Assume a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM php-fpm:8
ADD entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

In the entry-point script I just export a variable and print the environment

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export FOO=bar
env // just print the environment while entry point is running

exec "$@"
```

Then I build the image as `myimage` and use it to deploy a stack in docker swarm mode

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml teststack


// The docker-compose.yml file used is the following:

app:
  image: myimage:latest
  environment:
    APP_ENV: production
```

Now the question: If a check the logs of the `app` service I can see (because of the `env` command in the entry point) that the FOO variable is exported

```
docker service logs teststack_app 

teststack_app.1.nbcqgnspn1te@soulatso    | PWD=/var/www/html
teststack_app.1.nbcqgnspn1te@soulatso    | FOO=bar
teststack_app.1.nbcqgnspn1te@soulatso    | HOME=/root
```

However if I login in the running container and manually run `env` the FOO variable is not shown

```
docker container exec -it teststack_app.1.nbcqgnspn1tebirfatqiogmwp bash

root@df9c6d9c5f98:/var/www/html# env // run env inside the container

PWD=/var/www/html
HOME=/root
// No FOO variable :(
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A debugging shell you launch via `docker exec` isn't a child process of the main container process, and doesn't run the entrypoint itself, so it doesn't see the environment variables that are set there.

Depending on what you're trying to do, there are a couple of options to get around this.

If you're just trying to inspect what your image build produced, you can launch a debugging container instead.  The command you pass here will override the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, and when your entrypoint script does something like `exec "$@"` to run the command it gets passed, it will run this command instead.  This lets you inspect things in an environment just after your entrypoint's first-time setup has happened.

```
docker-compose run app env | grep FOO
docker-compose run app bash
```

Or, if the only thing your entrypoint script is to set environment variables, you can explicitly invoke it.

```
docker-compose exec app ./entrypoint.sh bash
```

**It is important that your entrypoint script accept an ordinary command as parameters.**  If it is a shell script, it should use something like `exec "$@"` to launch the main container process.  If your entrypoint ignores its parameters and launches a fixed command, or if you've set `ENTRYPOINT` to a language interpreter and `CMD` to a script name, these debugging techniques will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your first two lines made everything clear. BTW I do use `exec "$@"` but I forgot to add it to my question. I will edit it to include it. Thank you again